# Как грамотно переписать календарь?

Tags: javascript

Имею сайт необычных подарков, на сайте стоит самый банальный выбор даты через select.
Недавно поменял дизайн сайта, решил также сделать красивый календарь для выбора даты.
Начала углубляться в изучение js, и понеслась.
Я знаю что есть уже готовые скрипты, но хотелось написать все самостоятельно, так сказать понять как это работает изнутри.

Неделю пытался заставить работать свой скрипт, но даже не мог подумать, что это так сложно.
Якобы все заработало, но после того как начинаешь тестировать, видишь, то дата некорректно выводится, то день недели неверно выставляет, то количество дней неверное и т.д.

Буквально парочку часов назад мой скрипт заработал так как и задумано. Но я понимаю, что я многое упустил или написал лишнего. Вот и решил поинтересоваться у людей который в этом понимают.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно и нужно убрать из скрипта лишнее, или как правильно скомпоновать код для лучшей его работы.

ПРОШУ не ругаться, я только учусь).

Весь код загрузил для теста.

Всем заранее спасибо!

```js
let md = ["1947", "Февраль", "28"];
let days = ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'];


// ===================== Создаем option
function createSelectOption(sel, mass_md, calen) {
  let s_opt = document.createElement("option");
  s_opt.value = sel;
  s_opt.innerHTML = sel;

  if (sel == mass_md) {
    s_opt.setAttribute("selected", "");
  }
  calen.append(s_opt);
}

// Создаем разметку с месяцами select
let aMounth = new Array("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь"),
  calendar__month = document.getElementById("calendar__month"),
  calendar__month_opt = document.querySelectorAll("#calendar__month option");

for (let i = 0; i < aMounth.length; i++) {
  createSelectOption(aMounth[i], md[1], calendar__month);
}

// Определяем какой под номером месяц по его названию
function mounthIndex(e) {
  let result;
  aMounth.forEach((elem, index) => {
    if (e == elem) {
      result = index;
    }
  });
  return result + 1;
}

// Создаем разметку с годовым диапазоном select
let aYear = new Array(),
  calendar__year = document.getElementById("calendar__year"),
  calendar__year_opt = document.querySelectorAll("#calendar__year option");

for (let j = 1918; j <= 1991; j++) {
  aYear.push(j);
  createSelectOption(j, md[0], calendar__year);
}

// Создаем разметку для чисел дней
let calendar__num_dey = document.querySelector(".calendar__num_dey");
let inStart = 42; // всего ячеек

for (let d = 0; d < inStart; d++) {
  let calendar___date = document.createElement("div");
  calendar___date.classList.add("calendar___date");
  calendar__num_dey.append(calendar___date);
}


function startDates() {

  // ===============================
  const outGWD = getWeekDay(`${md[0]}/${mounthIndex(md[1])}/1`); // день недели
  let inOstatok = +getWeekDayIndex(outGWD) - 1; // день недели номер

  // ===== Получения дня недели
  function getWeekDay(gwd) {
    gwd = new Date(gwd);
    let day = gwd.getDay();
    return days[day];
  }

  // === Узнаем номер дня недели
  function getWeekDayIndex(d) {
    for (let key in days) {
      if (days[key] == d) d = key;
    }

    if (d == 0) d = 7;
    return d;
  }
  // ===============================


  // ===== Узнаем кол.во дней в месяце
  Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function() {
    return 32 - new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
  };

  // текущий месяц
  let inMounthThis = new Date(md[0], mounthIndex(md[1]) - 1, 1).daysInMonth();

  // прошедший месяц
  let inMountAfter = new Date(md[0], mounthIndex(md[1]) - 1, 0).daysInMonth();

  let inMountAfterMass = [];

  function dateRevers() {
    let out = [];
    for (let i = inMountAfter; i >= 1; i--) {
      out.push(i);
    }

    let outRes = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < inOstatok; j++) {
      outRes.push(out[j]);
    }

    outRes.reverse();
    inMountAfterMass = outRes;
  }
  dateRevers();
  // ===== end Узнаем кол.во дней в месяце


  function dateDeyNum() {

    // ======================== ДНИ
    let calDate = document.querySelectorAll(".calendar___date");

    // Сбрасываем все выделынные дни после нажатия
    function calDateRemove() {
      calDate.forEach(elem => {
        elem.classList.remove("active");
      });
    }

    let count = 1;
    // Текущий
    for (let i = inOstatok; i < inMounthThis + inOstatok; i++) {
      calDate[i].innerHTML = count++;

      calDate[i].classList.remove("calendar__date_nopointer");

      // Выделяем выбранный день
      calDate[i].onclick = function() {
        calDateRemove();
        this.classList.add("active");
        calendare(this.innerHTML);
      }

      // Отслеживаем выбранный день и оставляем активным
      if (calDate[i].innerHTML == md[2]) {
        calDateRemove();
        calDate[i].classList.add("active");
      }
    }

    // Прошедший
    for (let j = 0; j < inOstatok; j++) {
      calDate[j].innerHTML = inMountAfterMass[j];
      calDate[j].classList.add("calendar__date_nopointer");
    }

    // Будущий
    count = 1;
    for (let g = inMounthThis + inOstatok; g < inStart; g++) {
      calDate[g].innerHTML = count++;
      calDate[g].classList.add("calendar__date_nopointer");
    }

  }
  dateDeyNum();
}
startDates();


// =================================
// =================================

function calendare(thise, num) {

  // =========
  let calendar_date_title = document.querySelector(".calendar_date_title");

  if (thise !== undefined && num !== undefined) {
    let optinner = thise.options[thise.selectedIndex];

    if (optinner.value !== "") {

      if (num == 0) {
        md[num] = +optinner.innerHTML;
        calendar_date_title.children[2].innerHTML = optinner.innerHTML;
      } else if (num == 1) {
        md[num] = optinner.innerHTML;
        calendar_date_title.children[1].innerHTML = optinner.innerHTML;
      }

    }
  } else if (thise !== undefined && num == undefined) {
    md[2] = thise;
    calendar_date_title.children[0].innerHTML = thise;
  }
  // =========
  startDates();
  console.log(md);
}

// Записываем месяц в массив
calendar__month.onchange = function() {
  calendare(this, 1); // (значение, индекс в массиве)
}

// Записываем год в массив
calendar__year.onchange = function() {
  calendare(this, 0); // (значение, индекс в массиве)
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Marck+Script&display=swap');

/* MEDIA */

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .calendar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .calendar__item:nth-child(2) {
    border-radius: 0 0 34px 34px;
  }
}

body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 5% 3%;
}


/* =========== Calendar */

.calendar_wrp {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.calendar__item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5rem rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.calendar__item:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.calendar__item:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0 34px 34px 0;
}

.calendar___items {
  padding: 20px;
}

.calendar___items:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #f3f4f6;
}

.calendar__numer__item,
.calendar__num_dey {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.calendar__numer__item select {
  width: 48%;
  background-color: #f3f4f6;
  /* == */
  background-image: url(/img/strelka.svg);
  background-size: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 15px) center;
  /* == */
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.02rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.calendar__title_dey {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 25px 20px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #888;
}


/* === */

.calendar___date {
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0 0 13%;
  width: 46px;
  min-height: 46px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(255 255 255 / 100%);
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 3px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.calendar___date:nth-child(7n+7),
.calendar___date:nth-child(7n+6) {
  background: rgb(241, 229, 227);
  color: red;
}

.calendar___date:hover,
.calendar___date.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-size: 200%;
  border-color: transparent !important;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.calendar___date.active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FF6E5A 0, #f8ae56 51%, #f8ae56 100%);
}

.calendar___date:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff6d5a81 0, #f8ae56 51%, #f8ae56 100%);
}

.calendar__date_nopointer {
  box-shadow: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .3;
}


/* ===== Right block */

.calendar_date_title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.cdt_mounth {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.cdt_dey {
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 0.9;
}

.cdt_year {
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/other.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="body">

    <div class="calendar_wrp">
      <div class="calendar__item">

        <div class="calendar___items">
          <div class="calendar__numer__item">
            <select name="calendar__month" id="calendar__month" title="month">
              <option value="">Месяц</option>
            </select>
            <select name="calendar__year" id="calendar__year" title="year">
              <option value="">Год</option>
            </select>
            <div class="calendar__title_dey">
              <div>Пн</div>
              <div>Вт</div>
              <div>Ср</div>
              <div>Чт</div>
              <div>Пт</div>
              <div>Сб</div>
              <div>Вс</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="calendar___items calendar__num_dey"> </div>
      </div>

      <div class="calendar__item">
        <div class="calendar___items">
          <div class="calendar_date_title">
            <div class="cdt_dey">23</div>
            <div class="cdt_mounth">Февраль</div>
            <div class="cdt_year">1988</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Шаг к грамотности - использование `const` вместо `let` для значений которые не изменяются в процессе выполнения. Еще один шаг - использовать строгое сравнение (`===`) во всех случаях, где не предполагается допустимость автотипкаста (если не любишь ошибки, то таких случаев должно быть большинство). Еще один - отказ от использования конструктора `Array` (в пользу литералов / статик метода `from`). Это если беглым взглядом по коду пробежаться :) Мне лично, прежде всего очень-очень не нравится применяемое здесь именование переменных, но это уже относится к оформлению кода, а не к его "качеству".

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Принял все ваши замечания, сейчас все сделаю как вы написали. По поводу именование переменных, полностью с вами согласен, но пока не сообразил как правильно им давать имена.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Вообще, желание развиваться вызывает уважение, но этот вопрос наверное закроют как предполагающий мнения, а не однозначный ответ. Советую поискать пути улучшения кода не на stackoverflow, а банально в поисковике - тема же весьма популярная. Например, запрос в гугл `js best practices` дает кучу результатов. Еще можно посмотреть по запросу `js style guide`, т.к. гаæдлайны обычно содержат обоснования рекомендациям. Только нюанс: не стоит слепо следовать всему прочитанному и зубрить правила/клише: лучше взвешивать аргументы "за" и "против", рассуждать, и принимать собственные решения.

Comment: Забыл самый главный совет: _в обучении_, предпочитать количество качеству. Вполне нормально желание улучшить первые творения, создать "шедевр" - но попытки сделать это, тратят самый главный и самый ценный ресурс - мотивацию. Решай новые задачи, не застревай на том что уже сделано. Мастерство приходит с осознанием _огромного_ множества вещей, которые могут быть усвоены только _постепенно_. То есть, если в вопрос придет мастер и даст тебе переработанный код, это не поможет тебе стать лучшим программистом, чем ты есть. Поможет движение через новые задачи, и маленькие но регулярные порции знаний.

Comment: Просто надо осознавать (внимание, щас будет тревожно) что когда человек становится профессионалом, его мотивация рано или поздно иссякает, и работа становится всего лишь работой. Сейчас, пока все интересно и деятельность приносит кайф, твое "золотое время". Используй его по максимуму, закладывая фундамент тех навыков, которые определят твои будущие возможности: чем больше полезностей ты впитаешь в это время, _чем больший спектр задач_ научишься решать, тем сильнее станешь как специалист. Суть же не в том чтобы написать код, любой это может. Важнее способность создавать решения нетиповых задач.

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Общения и наставления при обучении  как раз и не хватает. Значит я движусь в правильном направлении.  Спасибо ещё оаз!